# android resource linking failed on textview

Tags: xml, android-studio

`android resource linking failed C:\Users\super\Desktop\Egyptian Pantheon\Egyptian Pantheon\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:42: error: resource xml/horus (aka com.example.egyptianpantheon:xml/horus) not found. error: failed processing manifest.`

Im trying to open my app my app but im having this problem is there anyway to fix this
[its says that i have a problem on line 42 but i dont see any problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mW4UX.png)

Comment: Please either include the code in the image instead of the image of the code or include both. Text is easier to deal with than an image.